# PHP cURL GET request is not returning JSON object

Tags: php, json, http, curl, get

I'm attempting to use PHP cURL to write a GET request that returns information in JSON format so I can decode it and store the header values accordingly in a Response class.  My request goes through successfully with a 200 Status code, but the actual response is coming back as a string rather than an object that I can work with.   I am using the generated code from Postman for cURL.

Here my PHP code for the request:

```
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "http://example.com",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-Type: application/json',
          'Accept: application/json')
        ));
        
       $result = curl_exec($curl);

       curl_close($curl);

       var_dump($result);
```

And here is the result I get from the var_dump($result):

```
string(1619) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Encoding: gzip
Age: 455672
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2020 21:42:08 GMT
Etag: "3147526947+ident+gzip"
Expires: Tue, 30 Jun 2020 21:42:08 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
Server: ECS (sjc/4E73)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 648

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 2em;
        background-color: #fdfdff;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        box-shadow: 2px 3px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        div {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: auto;
        }
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
"
```

Comment: You can't force the site to return JSON if that's not what it does. You're accessing an ordinary web page, it returns HTML.

Comment: Why are you sending a `Content-type` header? `GET` requests don't send any contents.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, that makes sense.  My main goal is to  store the contents of the header in a variable, so it seems I need to manually parse from the response.    I realize now this was a pretty dumb question :) sorry!

Comment: Change from `GET` to `HEAD`, then it will only return the header.